TI TPS2372 PoE !BT pin interpretation
In this here app note:
How to Identify Allocated Power at PD Through TPH, TPL, and BT Pins
it says, at the bottom of page 2:

The BT output is not required to indicate how much power is allocated to the PD by an
IEEE802.3bt compliant PSE. However, it gives additional information on the Type of PSE that is connected

What is one to make of this statement? It's about one pin that can be 0 or 1. This "it doesn't have reliable information, but it kinda does", I find confusing.

The tables in the document (along with the statement) seem clear enough to me. What about them do you find confusing?

That's great for you

And where do these words come from: "it doesn't have reliable information, but it kinda does" <-- they don't appear to be in the linked document yet you have them in quotes as if they do.

The TPS2372 datasheet describes the BT pin as:

Indicates that a PSE applying an IEEE802.3bt (Type 3 or 4) mutual identification scheme has been identified. Open-drain, active-low output referenced to RTN.

Overview of 802.3bt - Power over Ethernet standard on the ethernet alliance site contains the following in section 5.3. Mutual identification:

Mutual identification allows a PSE to discover the Type of the PD to which it is connected, and a PD to learn the Type of the PSE to which it is connected. There are a few blind spots in the mechanism, as it is not always possible to determine the connected device Type. However, the specification is designed such that in case of ambiguity, the assigned Class provides all the
required information to ensure interoperability.

So, my understanding is that under some conditions the BT pin on the TPS2372 may fail to identify if the PD using the TPS2372 is being powered by a PSE which implements IEEE802.3bt. However, the assigned Class should ensure interoperability between the PD and PSE.
